# How to convert Eigen::Matrix4f to Eigen::Affine3f

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to convert a matrix from Eigen::Matrix4f to Eigen::Affine3f 
Any one help?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Eigen::Affine3f` is a typedef of `Eigen::Transform<float, 3, Eigen::Affine>`.
According to the [reference](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Transform.html), the type has a member function `MatrixType & matrix ()` which gives you matrix interface.

```
Eigen::Matrix4f a;
Eigen::Affine3f b;
b.matrix() = a;
```

Answer (score 9):

`operator=` will do:

```
Matrix4f M;
Affine3f F;
F = M;
```